# Skip header from next file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, merge, header

While merging multiple number of CSV files, I can either getting headers from all the file or none of the headers at all. I want header from only 1st file as all file have same header and I am merging column below column.

I am a newbie in python. Actually there are 23 same name CSV file in different sub folder. I am using a loop to read them line by line. From that i want only the 1st file header.

This is my code:

```
 import os, sys
`import pathlib

    # Specify directory
    # In your case, you may want something like the following
    my_directory = 'C:/Users/Arijeet/Downloads'
    file = pathlib.Path("out.csv")
    if file.exists ():
      print("file found\nremoving")
      os.remove('out.csv')
    else:
      print("file not find\ncreating")


    counter = 1

    # Start the loop
    for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(my_directory):
      for special_file in files:
        if special_file == 'iono_tropo.csv':
          file_path = os.path.join(folder, special_file)


          # Open and read
          with open(file_path) as read_file:
            print('Reading iono_tropo csv file ' + str(counter))
            lines=read_file.readlines()
            with open ("out.csv","a+") as f:
              f.writelines(lines)

            counter += 1
```

What can I do?

Comment: I suggest use pandas to do that. https://pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you mean, but this should do the trick if you want to merge some csv's and only keep the header from the first.

```
with open ("file1.csv", "r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    data[-1] += "\n"                #Otherwise data from next file will be on the same line


for filename in ["file2.csv", "file3.csv", "file4.csv", "file5.csv"]:
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        file.readline()             #Skips the header for all the other files
        data += file.readlines()
        data[-1] += "\n"            #Otherwise data from next file will be on the same line


#Creating the merged file
with open("merged.csv", "w") as merged:
    for line in data:
        merged.write(line)
```

Comment: Let me know if it helped or not !

Comment: No it doesn't help. It's keep all the headers. Merged file has a row gap between two file.( With header)

Comment: Okay weird, its working fine for my csv's. Can I get a link to your csv's or do you have some sort of example file?